# Рекурсия по сложно-вложенному JSON

Tags: javascript

Нужна рекомендация по составлению следующего алгоритма:

Есть ситуация, при которой может имется JSON совершенно разного формата. В один момент времени он может быть таким:

```
{"root": {
  "child": "test_txt"
  }
}
```

В другой момент времени может быть таким:

```
{"root": {
  "child_one": {
    "child_of_childOne": {
      "attr1":"test_txt"
    }
  },
  "child_two": {
    "child_of_childTwo": {
      "attr2":"test_txt"
    }
  },
  "child_three": {
    "child1_of_childThree": {
      "attr3":"test_txt"
    }
    "child2_of_childThree": {
      "attr4": {
        "the_deepest_attr": "test_txt"
      }
    }
  },
};
```

и даже еще сложнее и еще более вложенным может быть в другой момент времени.

Что необходимо? - необходимо написать функцию, которая будет перебирать все ветки до самого глубокого атрибута (до string "text_txt") и сохранять имя самого глубокого атрибута с его значением (как если бы из примера выше необходимо было бы получить все attr)

Всё было бы просто, если бы ветка была одна, но тут может быть много веток с разными уровнями вложенности. Кроме того, имена ключей в таком JSON неизвестны, поэтому find'ом особо не попользуешься.

Моё направление мыслей такое: брать каждый объект и рекурсивно обходить его, пока не встречу атрибут со строкой. Если у объекта несколько "детишек" - запоминать его, сохраняя в массиве. По мере обхода "детей" - удалять их из массива.

Но я не уверен, что это верный подход, решил посоветоваться. Возможно, у кого-нибудь есть готовое решение. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Про рекурсию - правильно мыслите. Не ясно только про массив, в который вы добавляете child и удаляете их от туда, с какой целью это делается? (они ведь и так будут сохранятся в стеке, поскольку алгоритм рекурсивный). Или в этот массив нужно все результаты найденные складировать? (тогда не понятно почему может понадобится удалять от туда элементы).

Comment: Обходить потомков `root`, считать уровень вложенности каждого потомка с запоминанием глубины, ключом и значением глубочайшего. Если следующих будет глубже - поменять на новых "лидеров". Нет - идти дальше.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian массив я думал использовать, как операционный. Т.е. вот зашел я в root, вижу, что там 3 элемента - взял первый, остальные запомнил, чтобы когда я закончу с первым - сразу перейти ко второму, потом к третьему. Иначе, как я пойму, что первый элемент я уже обошел? Т.е. массив планировал использовать как map для будущих обходов.

Comment: Вы можете просто в цикле обходить всех детей, и для каждого, если он объект - вызвать рекурсивно эту же функцию, если строка - сохранить результат.

Answer (score 2):

Как дополнение к комментарию (только для того, чтобы концепцию показать):

```js
var j = {
  "root": {
    "child_one": {
      "child_of_childOne": {
        "attr1": "test_txt0"
      }
    },
    "child_two": {
      "child_of_childTwo": {
        "attr2": "test_txt1"
      }
    },
    "child_three": {
      "child1_of_childThree": {
        "attr3": "test_txt2"
      },
      "child2_of_childThree": {
        "attr4": {
          "the_deepest_attr": "test_txt3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

function traverse(o) {
  var i;
  for (var k in o) {
    i = o[k];
    if (typeof i === 'string') {
      console.log(i);
    } else if (typeof i === 'object') {
      traverse(i);
    }
  }
}

traverse(j);
```

Comment: Вроде бы, подходит =) Сейчас проверю на тех JSON'ах, что у меня уже есть